# Replace Values in a JSON file

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am new to PowerShell. I have three files **output1.txt**, **output2.txt**, **deployer.json**

**output1.txt**

```
db-tenant.rds.amazonaws.com
```

**output2.txt**

```
dev-51-db-global.rds.amazonaws.com
```

**deployer.json**

```
{
"user":"some_user",
"url":"some_url"
"urlglobal":"some_global_url",
"db":"some_db"
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
"user":"some_user",
"url":"db-tenant.rds.amazonaws.com"
"urlglobal":"dev-51-db-global.rds.amazonaws.com",
"db":"some_db"
}
```

I want to get the result from **output1.txt** and replace the value in **url** in the **deployer.json** file

I also want to get the result from **output2.txt** and replace it with the value in **urlglobal** in the **deployer.json** file

Here is a script I started with

**script.ps1**

```
$templatecontent = Get-Content -Path .\deployer.json
```

Comment: You can use `ConvertFrom-Json` to convert it to a proper PowerShell object, modify it the way you like and use `ConvertTo-Json` to get the desired JSON.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple, hopefully the code is self-explanatory.

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\deployer.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.url = Get-Content 'path\to\output1.txt'
$json.urlglobal = Get-Content 'path\to\output2.txt'
```

If you want to test the code without using external files:

```
$url = 'db-tenant.rds.amazonaws.com'
$urlglobal = 'dev-51-db-global.rds.amazonaws.com'

$json = @'
{
"user":"some_user",
"url":"some_url",
"urlglobal":"some_global_url",
"db":"some_db"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.url = $url
$json.urlglobal = $urlglobal
```

Then **`$json | ConvertTo-Json`** outputs:

```
{
    "user":  "some_user",
    "url":  "db-tenant.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "urlglobal":  "dev-51-db-global.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "db":  "some_db"
}
```